# This content requires HDCP for playback - Airplay on iPhone 5S not working

Tags: iphone, ios, appletv, airplay, hdcp

After getting the iPhone 5S, I have been having problems with the AppleTV connection. Sometimes it just drops as soon as I start Airplay mode from the iPhone, and most of the other times some error appears about HDCP. I never had these problems with the iPhone 4S and tried updating the AppleTV and that has fixed nothing.

How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: Just to verify, you have the TV on and on the correct input when you start Airplay? I had HDCP problems if I started streaming before changing the TV to the correct input.

Comment: @onik Yes. It works fine with the 4S but not the 5S.